# select mysql statement where current time is at least 60+ minutes from timestamp

Tags: mysql, select

I have a database with a timestamp field called DATECREATED and I am trying to run a select statement to retrieve all records where current time is at least 60+ minutes from timestamp

Eg.

timestamp is 2012-10-29 12:08:11.

I want to retrieve a record only if it has passed 60 minutes from the timestamp above. So if the time is 13:09, or 15:09, it should be retrieved. If the time is 12:15, it should return 0;

Any help would be greatly appreciated as other answers here haven`t helped so far.

Thanks.

Comment: Your example seems to be the opposite of what you said in the first paragraph. Do you want the records where DATECREATED is 60 minutes after current time, or the records where the current time is 60 minutes after DATECREATED? It's confusing because you sometimes use "timestamp" to mean the field in the table, and sometimes to mean the current time.

Comment: Either way, this should be an utterly trivial WHERE clause, like the one in juergen d's answer. What have you tried, and why didn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
where DATECREATED - interval 60 minute <= now()
```

See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8f51/3)

Comment: thanks gents. I tried Juergen`s query but it didn`t work. I need to return true for all DATECREATED records that passed 60 minutes. I hope that makes sense. So if the DATECREATED time is 12:08 and the current time is 13:09 or 15:09 or anytime after 60 minutes, it should return the record.

Comment: very strange juergen. i ran the fiddle but it returned empty. my query also returned empty. I am trying to pull every user that hasn't closed a session within 60 minutes. IF their session is open after 60 minutes, I need to know who they are.

Comment: Hi Juergen, I tried your fiddle but it didn't work. I just want all records past 60 minutes from DATECREATED. I don't believe intervals should be used but I could be wrong.

Comment: I changed the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8f51/3). Please check it again.

Answer (score 1):

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 60 MINUTE` returns the time that was 60 minutes ago. Any time less than or equal to that value should be, well, at most 60 minutes old.

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `datecreated` <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 60 MINUTE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
where DATECREATED between subdate(timestamp, interval 60 minute) 
                      and adddate(timestamp, interval 60 minute)
```

by using a `between` like this with two constant values (calculated once per query), the index on `DATECREATED` will be used (if one exists)